# How to change property of checkboxes from a checkbox?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

Hi guys im a newbie on php & mysql. I would like to ask how to change checkbox's property from  unchecked to checked from a single checkbox. For this case i am displaying the query from my database and i want to have some function like an email's inbox that once we check the control checkbox all the checkboxes in the row will be checked also.

Thank you in advance...

By the way, here is my code in php and java script,

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        if ($("#checkAll").is(':checked')) {
            $(".select").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".select").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Then php code:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        if(isset($_POST['department'])){
                    $department=$_POST['department'];
                    $course=$_POST['course'];
                    $level=$_POST['level'];

                    if ($department=="0"){
                        echo "Please select Department!";
                    }else if (($department!="0")&&($course=="0")&&($level =='0')){
                        $query = "SELECT* FROM studaccnt WHERE dept='$department' ORDER BY fname asc";
                        $result = mysql_query($query,$link)
                            or die ("Invalid query".mysql_error());
                        echo "<table border=0 align=center style='table-layout:fixed'>";
                        echo "<tr align = center bgcolor = '#A9F5FE' >";
                        echo "<td width=35><input type='checkbox' name='checkAll' id='checkAll' title='select all'>
                                <td width=100><strong>Family Name</strong></td><td width=100><strong>Given Name</strong></td>";
                        echo "</td><td width=30><strong>M.I.</strong></td>";
                        echo "<td width=160><strong>Department</strong> </td>";
                        echo "<td width=100><strong>Program</strong> </td>";
                        echo "<td width=30><strong>Level</strong> </td>";
                        echo "<td width=100><strong>Contact Number</strong> </td>";
                        echo "<td width=300><strong>Present Address</strong> </td>";
                        "</tr>"; 
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH))
                        {
                                $msgcode=$row["studid"];
                                $message=$row["fname"];
                                //echo "<td width=230><a href=editmsg.php?cmd=edit&msgcode=$msgcode><strong>$row[3]</strong>";
                                //echo "<td width=330><a href=editmsg.php?cmd=edit&msgcode=$msgcode>$row[5]";
                                echo "<tr class=btnav style='table-layout:fixed' bgcolor='#E0FFC1' onmouseover=style.backgroundColor='#CCFF99';
                                        onmouseout=style.backgroundColor='#E0FFC1'>";
                                echo "<td width=50 align=center><input type='checkbox' name='select' value='checkbox'>";  
                                echo "<td width=40>$row[1]";
                                echo "<td width=40>$row[2]";
                                echo "<td width=30 align=center>$row[3]";
                                echo "<td width=150>$row[4]";
                                echo "<td width=80>$row[5]";
                                echo "<td width=40 align=center>$row[6]";
                                echo "<td width=130 align=center>$row[7]";
                                echo "<td width=200>$row[8]";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                echo "</table>";
                            $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    }
```

Comment: what  have you tried ?

Comment: you need to share your sample html and what you have tried so far

Comment: Why these much of downvotes. He is a newbie to SO.Give him some time to explain the problem.

Comment: First i tried java script to to the job..like this:<script>
   $(function () {
  $("#checkAll").click(function () {
   if ($("#checkAll").is(':checked')) {
    $(".select").prop("checked", true);
   } else {
    $(".select").prop("checked", false);
    }
   });
  });
   </script> Guys my apology i don't know where i can post my code in php...:(

Comment: By the way i have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using JQUERY, put this in your `head tag` :

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then below your head, to set Checked:

```
function setChecked(string checkbox)
   {
        $("#" + checkbox).prop('checked', true);
   }
```

to Uncheck:

```
function setChecked(string checkbox)
   {
        $("#" + checkbox).prop('checked', false);
   }
```

Call these methods in your PHP.
Good luck.

Comment: hope so, try calling your function like: setChecked('checkAll')